# Does HttpUrlConnection have to be set up to work on public wifi connections?

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection

The app I'm currently working on is in it's first Beta stage, it was discovered this class couldn't complete its task when using public wifi.

Has anyone had this issue before? Would have anything to do with SSL certificates used by the server it is trying to connect to?

```
public class NetGameList implements Callable<String> {

    private DatabaseManager DBM = DatabaseManager.getInstance();

    private JSONArray jsonArray;

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();

        try {

            URL url = new URL(Constants.NETBUILDGAMELISTURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            jsonParam.put("TAG", Constants.HTTPTHREE);
            jsonParam.put("receiverid", Constants.NETUSERFACEBOOKID);

            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");

            //write data to server-------------------------------------------------------------------------
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            outputStream.write(jsonParam.toString().getBytes("utf-8"));

            //flush&close the stream
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();


            //Get result from server
            InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
            String line = "";

            ArrayList<String> jsonArrays = new ArrayList<String>();

            while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {

                jsonArrays.add(line);
            }
            responseStreamReader.close();

            for (String game : jsonArrays) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(game);

                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    if (!DBM.gameExists(jObject.get("GameId").toString())) {

                        DBM.addGame(jObject.get("GameId").toString(), jObject.get("SenderId").toString(),
                                jObject.get("GameTrack").toString(), jObject.get("FileLocation").toString(), getDateTime());
                    } else {

                        DBM.updateGames(jObject.get("GameId").toString(), jObject.get("SenderId").toString(),
                                jObject.get("GameTrack").toString(), jObject.get("FileLocation").toString(), getDateTime());
                    }
                }
            }

            responseStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return Constants.NETOPCOMPLETE;
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed your Java tag. This question is purely about Android, it has nothing to do with Java. Please refrain from adding Java tags to questions that a Java dev cannot answer without Android experience.

Comment: @drewmore http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254642/deleting-java-tag-from-questions-tagged-androidjava

Comment: Please remove the junk from your code sample and just keep the part that allows to reproduce the issue. Also, as I commented in my answer, don't swallow exceptions, what are the logs, and what is the value of `jsonArrays` when it doesn't complete?

Answer (score 0):

To use WIFI, you should add the permission:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

to your manifest file.

Comment: The permissions in the manifest are correct, this is only an issue with public wifi. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, "public" wifi requires a web-based login

Comment: This is true, the device had been signed in to access the wifi connection via the browser. So I assumed it would allow the ip address of the device access? or would the login credentials have to be added to the UrlConnection via addProperty?

Comment: Well, I don't know. Just debug the value of jsonArrays. And don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: This isn't really helpful by answering "I don't know."

Comment: And it's not useful question to just say _couldn't complete its task_. Stackoverflow is not a crowdsourced debugger.